# State update issue in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

I am creating CRUD Application using React to manage users.
I fetch the user data from 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'. I tried to delete data using the fetch DELETE method but it doesn't work. so I made a copy of users and performed the delete operation there.

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import Table from './components/Table';

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
  const fetchUserHandler = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    const data = await response.json();

    // Made the copy of the data
    let userCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    setUsers(userCopy);
  };
  console.log('users in app comp: ', users);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='fetch-btn'>
          <button className='btn' onClick={fetchUserHandler}>
            Fetch User
          </button>
        </div>
        <Table users={users} updateState={setUsers} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The DELETE operation is done in TABLE component inside deleteHandler():

```js
export default function Table(props) {
  console.log('props.users in table comp: ', props.users);

  const deleteHandler = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    props.users.splice(
      props.users.findIndex((u) => u.id == id),
      1,
    );
    props.updateState(props.users);
  };

  return (
    <div className='users-table'>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {props.users &&
            props.users.map((user, key) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <tr key={key}>
                    <td>{user.id}</td>
                    <td>{user.name}</td>
                    <td>{user.email}</td>
                    <td>{user.phone}</td>
                    <td>
                      <button style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}>Edit</button>
                      <button style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }} onClick={() => deleteHandler(user.id)}>
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </>
              );
            })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the console look like:

[image of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeQvY.png)

Problem:

- the State is updating in App component but the Table componet is not re-rendering.
- I want to update my table after delete operation.
- I am assigning key prop to every row, why it is showing warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is in-place modification operation. So it will return you same reference of an array. If you want to update state you have to pass different reference of an array as:

[`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-sun-n4ssmw?file=/src/components/Table.js)

```
props.updateState([...props.users]);
```

One more thing, It is not recommended to user `index` as a `key` so better to use `unique id`

```
<tr key={user.id}>
```

You should add key on the direct element in the callback function, You are adding on `tr` not on the `<> ... </>` not on `Fragment`.

Either you can add `key` on `React.Fragment` or just remove it. Since you are already adding `key` on the `tr`.

```
{props.users &&
            props.users.map((user, key) => {
              return (  // Removed Fragment
                <tr key={user.id}>
                  <td>{user.id}</td>
```

Or use as: [`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-roentgen-n845rm?file=/src/components/Table.js:566-708)

```
{props.users &&
  props.users.map((user, key) => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment key={user.id}>
        <tr>
          <td>{user.id}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am new to Reactjs, and you clearly explain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the updateState with filtering the oldState like this:

```js
  const deleteHandler = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    props.updateState((oldState) => oldState.filter((item) => item.id !== id))

  };
```